# Exporting plot data from R to Excel

Tags: r, export-to-excel, gbm, dismo

I am using packages gbm and dismo to create regression tree models in R. 
I first create the model:

```
gen_1 <- gbm.step(data = cray_data, gbm.x = 14:23, gbm.y = 11, family = "bernoulli", tree.complexity = 3, learning.rate = 0.01, bag.fraction = 0.5)
```

Then create the plots for this model (gen_1):

```
p <- gbm.plot(gen_1, n.plots=6, write.title=FALSE)
```

I need to export the data from these plots (p) in an excel file; not the jpeg created, but the data that it has been created from.

I have been trying things like write.table but I am relatively new to R and haven't had any luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should post a [MCVE]  that starts with loading the package that has these functions as well as a dataset for testing.

Comment: Are you trying to export `cray_data`?

Comment: I am trying to export the data from the plots (p). cray_data is the dataset I am using to create the model.

Comment: I can post my code but the datasets needed to create the model are quite large and I'm not really sure how to go about posting them.

Comment: What does the "data from the plots" mean exactly? What are the exact values in the rows and columns that you want to create. As already requested, a reproducible example would be very helpful. Maybe use examples from the help pages.

Comment: [See this answer by GNG, at least 30 characters](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/144871/43360)